# Adding an image tag breaks navbar in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3Ztx.png)Everytime I add a image with `img` tag to the html file the navbar stops working? Anyone have an idea... thank you in advance. I thought at first it had something to do with the img-responsive class but it seems not to be the issue.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


        <title>
               About 
        </title>
        <meta name="description" content="is applying to be a full stack developer student .">


        <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">


    </head>
    <body>


        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
          <div class="container">

            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNav" aria-expanded="false" >
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNav">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="about.html">ABOUT <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="./">RESUME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#./">PROJECTS</a></li>

              </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

          </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
        </nav>

        <div class="jumbotron">
          <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6">.col-md-6</div>
                  <div class="col-md-6">
                      <p class="intro">Hi, my name is<br> Angel<br>and I am a</p>
                      <div class="textShow">
                          <div class="textSlider fade">
                              <p><strong>DEVELOPER</strong></p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="textSlider fade">
                                  <p><strong>M.B.A.</strong></p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="textSlider fade">
                                  <p><strong>VETERAN</strong></p>
                              </div>
                              <div class="textSlider fade">
                                  <p><strong>FOODIE</strong></p>
                              </div>
                          </div>

                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 middleOne">
                <p class="groundUp">Creating and building from the ground up</p>
                //this breaks navbar<img class=" img-responsive beet1" src="Graphics/beetv1.svg" alt="RedBeet"/>
            </div>
        </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

If there is a sample code of the responsive menu along with the photo in the menu, please send a comment in this post. If it is possible, please develop my same code so that I can put a picture in its menu.

Comment: could you also post the image tag you're trying to add?

Comment: click on "enter description here"

Comment: that image could be a little too big for the navbar. Typical bootstrap navbar height is around ```50px``` could you maybe give the image tag a fixed height of 50px (or 20px if you'd like to keep some padding)

Comment: But I'm adding it to the jumbotron... it's out of the nav container

Comment: Oh ok, Just tried this on jsbin and it looks like you may want to add ```max-width:100%``` to the image in order to have it not overflow out of ```.col-md-6``` here's the link: https://jsbin.com/riqekapeba/1/edit?html,output